# Dell Inspiron 5378 won't boot (or complete POST) after black screen

Tags: boot, laptop, dell-inspiron, post

I have a Dell Inspiron 5378 (i7 7th Gen) that was delivered in June 2017 (out of warranty). It is running Windows 10.

In the middle of use today under AC adapter power, it simply shut off (black screen) and will not boot. At no time is there any screen output from any of my troubleshooting attempts (see below).

The laptop does report a "no memory" POST code error with all RAM removed but does not boot or display the Dell logo screen.

I welcome any suggestions to support continued troubleshooting and have access to a multimeter and a 50 MHz oscilloscope, if applicable. Likewise, if this issue is likely unresolvable, I welcome the hard truth. Thank you.

**Troubleshooting Attempts**

Initially, pressing and holding the power button for 30-40 seconds would briefly illuminate the power and battery-status LED at the start and give 3 white flashes before attempting to start again. Attempting to turn the laptop on with the Fn or F2 key depressed does nothing.

Pressing the power button would light the LED (white) briefly before turning off. There was no sound from the fan and no other signs of initiating or completing POST.
The laptop exhibited the same behavior in the following power configurations:

- AC adapter and battery connected
- Battery only, AC adapter unplugged
- AC adapter only, battery disconnected

Unplugging and plugging in the AC adapter and attempting to power the laptop on showed the same transient LED illumination. (The LED turning off may simply indicate AC power with a full battery charge.) The green LED on the AC adapter (charger) stays on.

After performing a hard reset (unplug AC adapter, disconnect battery, and hold power button for 30 seconds), attempts to power it up enabled the fan to come on. Under the power conditions above, the LED lights up as before and the fan comes on for just over 11 seconds before the fan turns off. The keyboard lights up for the same duration as the fan is active.

Disconnecting the CMOS battery for 3 hours (after disconnecting the AC adapter and battery and holding the power button to discharge) made no difference.

**Additional Diagnostics**

- Removing each 8 GB RAM stick, testing boot with each of them individually and swapping positions made no difference.
- Removing the SSD made no difference.
- Removing the WLAN from its socket made no difference.
- Removing both RAM sticks ***did*** result in a system diagnostic output of no memory or RAM detected (2 amber flashes followed by 3 white flashes).

**Other Details**

Modifications from the base configuration include increasing the RAM from 8 to 16 GB, replacing the HDD with a larger SSD, and replacing the battery. All of these changes were done more than a year ago. I have performed Dell's recommended BIOS updates, but not the latest from 24Sep2021.

Comment: Did any other electrical appliances get damaged around the same time (could maybe have been caused by a power surge)?

Comment: No. It did not appear to have anything to do with a power surge.